# R: Bar plot turns empty after multiplying values in the data frame and plotting again

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, visualization

First, I had a df like this:

[image]

And when I plot it, it is otherwise fine, but I want to do it with real percentages. Therefore, I created another df like this one below. I just multiplied the pct by 100, and now the percentages are like I want them to be in the df:

[image]

The difference is, that with the new df the bar plot is EMPTY. What is the matter?

Here is the code of the plot:

```
ggplot(remove_missing(mydata), mapping = aes(x = value, y = pct)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = value),
           width = 0.30) +
  scale_y_continuous(lim=c(0,1),labels=scales::percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(pct,1)), colour="black", size=3) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c('option1' = "blue", 
               'option2' = "blue", 
               'option3' = "blue",
               'option4' = "blue",
               'option5' = "blue",
               'option6' = "blue",
               'option7' = "blue",
               'option8' = "blue",
               'option9' = "blue",
               'option10' = "blue",
               'option11' = "blue",
               'option12' = "blue",
               'option13' = "blue"),
    drop = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "", y = "pct of responders") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r =  30, b = 20, l = 5.5),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "plain"),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "lightgrey"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "grey"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(
      size = 11,
      face = "plain",
      hjust = 0
    ), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      size = 11,
      face = "plain",
      hjust = 0
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12),
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x)
    str_wrap(x, width = 20))
```

My data

```
structure(list(variable = c("option1", "option1", "option10", 
"option10", "option11", "option11", "option12", "option12", "option13", 
"option13", "option2", "option2", "option3", "option3", "option4", 
"option4", "option5", "option5", "option6", "option6", "option7", 
"option7", "option8", "option8", "option9", "option9"), value = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 10L, NA, 11L, NA, 12L, NA, 13L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 
5L, NA, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, 8L, NA, 9L, NA), .Label = c("option1", 
"option2", "option3", "option4", "option5", "option6", "option7", 
"option8", "option9", "option10", "option11", "option12", "option13"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), n = c(98L, 49L, 107L, 40L, 
59L, 88L, 46L, 101L, 9L, 138L, 133L, 14L, 50L, 97L, 98L, 49L, 
138L, 9L, 103L, 44L, 37L, 110L, 84L, 63L, 14L, 133L), pct = c(66.6666666666667, 
33.3333333333333, 72.7891156462585, 27.2108843537415, 40.1360544217687, 
59.8639455782313, 31.2925170068027, 68.7074829931973, 6.12244897959184, 
93.8775510204082, 90.4761904761905, 9.52380952380952, 34.0136054421769, 
65.9863945578231, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 93.8775510204082, 
6.12244897959184, 70.0680272108844, 29.9319727891156, 25.1700680272109, 
74.8299319727891, 57.1428571428571, 42.8571428571429, 9.52380952380952, 
90.4761904761905)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), groups = structure(list(
    variable = c("option1", "option10", "option11", "option12", 
    "option13", "option2", "option3", "option4", "option5", "option6", 
    "option7", "option8", "option9"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 
        19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 25:26), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -13L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Most likely because you have not adjusted the limits, i.e. using `lim=c(0,1)` values larger than 1 get dropped.

Comment: Yeah. Use `scale_y_continuous(lim=c(0,100),labels=scales::percent)`

Comment: That solution produced another flaw though. Now the y-axis is in thousands

Comment: Try with `labels=~scales::percent(.x, scale = 1)`. scales::percent will by default multiply or scale by 100. So perhaps the better option would be to not multiply your values by 100 and instead use label=100*round(...). or `label=scales::percent(pct)` in geom_text

Comment: Thank you stefan. ```label=100*round``` works very well

Answer (score 0):

So, to finish this answer, this:

```
ggplot(remove_missing(mydata), mapping = aes(x = value, y = pct)) +
geom_col(aes(fill = value),width = 0.30) +
scale_y_continuous(lim=c(0,100)) +    # changed here per @ MrFlick3
geom_text(aes(label=round(pct,1)), colour="black", size=3) +  # changed here per @stefan
scale_fill_manual(
values = c('option1' = "blue", 
           'option2' = "blue", 
           'option3' = "blue",
           'option4' = "blue",
           'option5' = "blue",
           'option6' = "blue",
           'option7' = "blue",
           'option8' = "blue",
           'option9' = "blue",
           'option10' = "blue",
           'option11' = "blue",
           'option12' = "blue",
           'option13' = "blue"),
drop = FALSE) +
labs(x = "", y = "pct of responders") +
guides(fill = "none") +
 theme(
plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r =  30, b = 20, l = 5.5),
plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "plain"),
panel.background = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "lightgrey"),
axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "grey"),
axis.text.y = element_text(
  size = 11,
  face = "plain",
  hjust = 0
), 
axis.text.x = element_text(
  size = 11,
  face = "plain",
  hjust = 0
),
axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12) ) +

 coord_flip() +
 ggtitle("") +
 scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x)
   str_wrap(x, width = 20))
```